# How to interact with RISC-V CSRs by using GCC C code?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, riscv

this is my first question to be asked here on stackoverflow, so please be kind with me ;)

I'm new to RISC-V and low level C coding and I'm wondering how to manipulate the RISC-V CSRs using GCC C code.

A read of a specific CSR (e.g. MISA) looks easy: `csrr rd, 0x301` which is short for `csrrs rd, 0x301, x0` can be done e.g. with

```
int result;
asm("csrr %0, 0x301" : "=r"(result) : );
```

How can I convert the code above into some kind of function / callable unit with the following interface: `int read_csr(int csr_number)`?

Since the CSR number must be an immediate value in machine code, is it possible without generating the code on the fly (self modifying code)?

Thanks for your replies and discussion.

Joachim

Comment: Does it have to be `x0`, or can you let the compiler pick an arbitrary register for `"=r`"?  Like would `asm("csrrs rd, 0x301, %0" : "=r"(result) : );` work?  For the 2nd part, you can use `"i"` constraints to get compile-time constant inputs as an immediate.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for links to GCC dogs.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. Yes, the `x0` has a special meaning here which is "do not set any bits" (x0 is hardwired to 0 in RISC-V). For the second part (to have a different value instead of 0x301) I am aware of the `"i"` construct but unsure how to use it in form of a function as the parameter is not compile-time constant?

Comment: Oh I see, I was misinterpreting the question.  That does work and you're just asking how to use a value from C for the immediate.  Do you really want to be able to loop over CSRs or something?  The obvious solution is to make sure this can inline into callers by making it a macro (e.g. a GNU C Statement Expression) so you can use "I" or preprocessor tricks, or still as a function with `__attribute__((always_inline))` so it can see the compile-time constant even with optimization disabled.  Is that what you're looking for?  I mean obviously you *can* write self-modifying code, but yuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `I` constraint for an immediate constant argument:

```
inline int read_csr(int csr_num) __attribute__((always_inline)) {
    int result;
    asm("csrr %0, %1" : "=r"(result) : "I"(csr_num));
    return result; }
```

this will fail if you ever call it with an argument that is not a constant expression, as the `I` constraint requires a constant.

Comment: What does the `I` constraint gain in terms of performance here?

Comment: there is no performance gain, it can just be considered a bit cleaner as it gives the compiler/assembler mire insight what you are doing here.