# Inline assembly with function arguments

Tags: c, inline-assembly, riscv

I have a case that I want to automate my inline assembly inside a function.
`regx` has 32 bits, and `read` has 8 bits.

```
uint32_t *r(uint32_t regx){
  uint32_t *read;

  for(int i = 0; i<4; i ++){
  __asm__ volatile("csrr %0, regx" : "=r"(read));
  }
  return read;
}
```

`regx` is the argument that I want to change with different values (regx= 0x3A) for example.
I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you asking how you would use the value of the `regx` parameter in the inline assembly? You have already passed information about the `read` variable into the inline assembly; what problem are you having passing the `regx` parameter? Did you write `__asm__ volatile("csrr %0, regx" : "=r"(read));` yourself or just copy it from somewhere? In other words, do you know some syntax for inline assembly and just need help with this additional bit, or do you not know the inline assembly syntax at all? Does the `csrr` instruction take a register operand for the second operand?

Comment: What do you mean you want to “automate“ this?

Comment: According to you, then I'm have a misunderstanding?
I thought ```"=r"(read)```, is the output from ```regx```, and I have different register addresses for regx. So basically, I want to pass different address values (```regx```) to the inline assembly.

Comment: https://five-embeddev.com/riscv-isa-manual/latest/csr.html says `csrr` instructions need the CSR number as an immediate, so you need a `"I"(regx)` input constraint.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html).  And the function may need optimization to be enabled for constant-propagation to work.

Comment: I found the answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947716/how-to-interact-with-risc-v-csrs-by-using-gcc-c-code
Thank you Peter.